# Is it possible to set a cookie via Jersey AsyncResponse

Tags: java, asynchronous, cookies, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey AsyncResponse and want to set a cookie additional to an asynchronously set json response.

I found no possibility to do so, and wonder if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `.cookie()` while you're building the response:

```
asyncResponse.resume(
   Response.ok(stream, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   .cookie(new NewCookie("key","value")).build());
```